# Unnesting a 2D array of structs into a struct of 2D arrays

Tags: apache-spark

I have a column of type `array<array<struct<a: String, b: Int>>>`.

I want a column of type `struct<a: array<array<String>>, b: array<array<Int>>`.

Ideally, this procedure should unnest all struct fields automatically (i.e. without me having to specify fields "a" and "b" manually), but anything that works would be extremely helpful here.

Example code that I have (I'm trying to turn `ds` into `expected`).

```
case class Struct(foo: String, bar: Int)
case class Schema(structs: Vector[Vector[Struct]])

val ss = spark
import ss.implicits._

val ds = Seq(Schema(Vector(Vector(Struct("a", 1), Struct("b", 2)), Vector(Struct("c", 3))))).toDS

val expected = Seq(
    (Vector(Vector("a", "b"), Vector("c")), Vector(Vector(1, 2), Vector(3)))
).toDF("foo", "bar")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest solution is to use `transform` higher order function (introduced in Spark 2.4):

```scala
ds.selectExpr(
  "transform(structs, xs -> transform(xs, x -> x.foo)) as foo",
  "transform(structs, xs -> transform(xs, x -> x.bar)) as bar"
)
```

In older version you'll need either equivalent `udf`* or use typed `map`:

```scala
ds.as[Schema]
  .map(x => (
    x.structs.map(_.map(_.foo)), 
    x.structs.map(_.map(_.bar))
)).toDF("foo", "bar")
```

The former solution can be generalized:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def expand(ds: DataFrame, col: String) = {

  val fields = ds.schema(col).dataType match {
    case ArrayType(ArrayType(s: StructType, _), _) => s.fieldNames
  }
  val exprs = fields.map {
    field => expr(
      s"transform(`$col`, xs -> transform(xs, x -> x.`$field`)) as `$field`"
    )
  }
  ds.select(exprs: _*)
}

expand(ds.toDF, "structs")
```

The latter one probably not so much, unless you want to use Scala reflection (and that's a serious overkill).

---

* Something around these lines should do the trick:

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

def extract[T : TypeTag](field: String) = udf(
  (xs: Seq[Seq[Row]]) => xs.map(_.map(_.getAs[T](field)))
)

val extractString = extract[String] _
val extractInt = extract[Int] _

ds.select(
  extractString("foo")($"structs").as("foo"),
  extractInt("bar")($"structs").as("bar")
)
```